# PHP string replace with characters inbetween tags

Tags: php

I need help with my PHP, I'm using `str_ireplace()` and I want to filter something out and replace it with what I have.

I find it hard to explain what I am talking about so I will give an example below:

This is what I need

```
$string = "<error> " . md5(rand(0, 1000)) . time() . " </error> Test:)";
```

then I want to remove and replace the whole `<error> .... </error>` with nothing.

So the end outcome should just print `'Test:)'`.

Comment: Try using a regexp (using preg_replace), and be sure to define what exactly you want to replace. From your message above it's still rather hard to tell. And if a human can't tell, then a script is sure not to understand what you want ;)

Comment: As Tularis says, it's not at all clear currently what you're asking or what you wish to achieve. You may want to restructure the question, showing clearly what is the input and what is the desired output. You also want to discover regular expressions - www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not perfectly clear, but I believe I may understand what you are asking.  This code may do the trick:

```
$string = " " . md5(rand(0, 1000)) . time() . " Test:)";
$newstring = preg_replace("/.*?\ /i", "", $string);
```

This uses regular expressions to filter out everything that comes before the space (and also removes the space)